# SQL Server 2005 database in script

Tags: sql-server

I created a really small database in MSSQL Server 2005 in order to get the SQL it requires to create it on the fly, but I haven't been able to do so. Basically, I want the script that creates the database exactly as I created it using SQL Server Management Studio (I don't care about the data since the database is empty, I only want the schema). I know there is a way to do it, but I don't remember how.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right Click Database>Script Database As>Create To>Output option of your choice. I believe this is what you are referring to?

Comment: This will give them only the CREATE DATABASE script.  It won't script out any of their tables, etc.  If you right click on the database and select Tasks > Generate Scripts, this will provide you a wizard that will allow you to script out the database and all its objects.

Comment: Ahh did not know that! Guess I should pay a little more attention then.